# getParcelable() crashes due to null ifTable in AGP 8

Tags: android, parcelable, android-r8, android-gradle-plugin-8.0

I recently updated to AGP 8 and I released an update on to the play store. I am getting reports of some crashes in an area of code that was not changed recently. I am fairly confident this is a crash caused by the AGP 8 upgrade, specifically around R8 fullmode.

The code surrounding the crash is restoring the state of a layout manager.

Restoration code

```kotlin
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    oldRecyclerLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelableCompat(
        SIS_RECYCLER_LAYOUT_STATE,
    )
}
```

Save instance code

```
private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
...
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putParcelable(SIS_RECYCLER_LAYOUT_STATE, layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState())
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

}
```

The crash report indicates that reading a parcelable is crashing due to the ifTable of a class being null when `Class.isAssignableFrom()` is called on it. From [the AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a8a489492749b845cc2a85d67c664449d7b0b019/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/Class.java#171), I can see that an `ifTable` is a table of interfaces. I assume `isAssignableFrom` is using the `ifTable` to determine assignability however it was unable to read it due to the class being null. Unfortunately the error doesn't tell me which class is null.

Full stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.Object[] java.lang.Class.ifTable' on a null object reference in method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)'
       at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Class.java:579)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreatorInternal(Parcel.java:4865)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4778)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:4544)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:4324)
       at android.os.Parcel.-$$Nest$mreadValue()
       at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply(Parcel.java:4422)
       at android.os.Parcel$LazyValue.apply(Parcel.java:4381)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getValueAt(BaseBundle.java:394)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue(BaseBundle.java:374)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.getValue(BaseBundle.java:357)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.get(BaseBundle.java:696)
       at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:947)
       at com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.util.ext.BundleExtKt.getParcelableCompat(BundleExt.kt:21)
       at com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.summonerlookup.SummonerProfileFragment.onViewCreated(SummonerProfileFragment.kt:422)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3137)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1435)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2979)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2890)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3138)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1435)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2979)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2897)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
       at com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.activity.abs.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.kt:90)
       at com.ggstudios.lolcatalyst.activity.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1510)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8603)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4191)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

If anyone knows the cause or what the fix is, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the question. This AGP upgrade has been causing me so many headaches. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr the fix is to use `BundleCompat.getParcelable(Bundle, String, Class)` from `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0` instead of `getParcelable(String, Class)`.**

I think this crash is caused by an unfortunate combination of two things.

1. AGP 8 enabled R8's full mode by default. [R8's full mode strips default constructors and performs more aggresive optimizations.](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md#r8-full-mode)
2. The new `getParcelable(String, Class)` methods introduced in API 33 has some bugs if the Parcelable is not defined in a particular way. [This is documented here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/274185314)

It looks like the fragile implementation of `getParcelable(String, Class)` and R8 optimizing certain code is causing this crash. The fix for now appear to be to use the old `getParcelable(String)` method in API 33. Google has stated they have fixed the issue with `getParcelable(String, Class)` in API 34.

**Update**: `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0` contains a fix for this issue. It contains `BundleCompat.getParcelable(Bundle, String, Class)` which will only call the new `getParcelable(Bundle, Class)` function on Android U and above.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the issue. In relation to R8 take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/274185314 which has suggestions for keep rules or alternatively using the `androidx.core` JetPack library.

Comment: Cool. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `Intent::getParcelableExtra` and it also gets fixed by replacing it with `IntentCompat::getParcelableExtra`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this proguard rules inside the **proguard-rules.pro**

```
# Parcel reading may lookup/validate the parcel and creator via their
# inner-class relationship. Ensure the attributes are kept and the
# inner/outer relationship is soft pinned. The 'allowshrinking' option
# allows the classes to be removed if unused, but otherwise their attributes
# are retained.
-keepattributes EnclosingClass,InnerClasses
-keep,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class * implements android.os.Parcelable {}
-keep,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class * implements android.os.Parcelable$Creator {}
```